# When using Cognito credentials with AWS in a browser (javascript), keep getting "missing credentials" error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to upload a file to an S3 bucket of mine from a web browser using AWS' JavaScript SDK. My code looks like this:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    AccountId: 'dfhgdh',
    IdentityPoolId: 'fdagsd',
    RoleArn: 'fdafds'
});

var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test-bucket'}});
var pdfUpload = document.getElementById('pdf-uploads').files[0];

var params = {Key: pdfUpload.name, ContentType: pdfUpload.type, Body: pdfUpload};
bucket.putObject(params, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

However, whenever it reaches the putObject command, I keep getting an error back from AWS:

"Error: Missing credentials in config {message: "Missing credentials in config", code: "CredentialsError"..."

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and stupid here, but I can't figure out what for the life of me. (I get a different error when I try to just hardcode a bogus secret key in or something, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way I'm trying to set up cognito credentials.)

Comment: Can you include the full contents of the error message you receive? The CredentialsError seems to be cut off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that after debugging the JavaScript AWS SDK, the problem was that I wasn't setting the region before setting the credentials... And for some reason, I need to use the update method, as well. I think this seems like a bug with the SDK, but the following setup of AWS.config fixed my problem:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWS.config.update({
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        AccountId: '43243243243',
        RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::970123460807:role/Cognito_RigUpWebUnauth_DefaultRole',
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:432432-432432432-4324323423-423243'
    })
});
```

Comment: Is it safe to use upload via js , i mean we are exposing these credentials ? Or is it safe enough?

Comment: There's two things that still allow for a secure download: 1) You should configure your settings on S3 to only allow upload and download requests from your site's URL. 2) The client must know the name of a file in order to read it. So when uploading a file, you can use a random alphanumeric string of 14 or 15 characters as the folder name to ensure uniqueness and make it virtually impossible to guess a file name.

Comment: Okay point number does make alot of sense.. Thanks. Here is the url that i found trello uses... https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/55d37fa3bdcb50239ec4bdef/128x128/4e48c4322a0f7788898ed82ad0774fd4/add_new_prescription.png ..Is it the same approach ?

Comment: It would seem so. I don't remember what an s3 URL looks like when there's no directory, though. So I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

After configuring your credentials object, you will need to make a call to obtain those credentials by calling `refresh()`. You can then put your call to S3 inside the callback.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({...});

AWS.config.credentials.refresh(function(){
   // Your S3 code here...
});
```