# Refresh of AWS.config.credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, credentials, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to find a proper way of refreshing the AWS.config.credentials I get from Cognito. I'm using developer authorized identities and it works fine. I get the credentials and if I perform a refresh() the AWS.config.credentials.expireTime is also updated, as expected.

The credentials expire after one hour, so I thought I could use setTimeout to refresh the credentials and configure it based on the credentials.expireTime (I calculate the number of millis).

However, it seems like I have to perform the refresh much more often. The credentials keeps timing out before their time. The setTimeout-method works just fine if I reduce the delay to a much smaller amount, but I would prefer not to overdo the refresh.

Is this true, and if so how often do I need to do this? Having it refresh every 5 minutes or so seems excessive :/

**Recurring refresh**

```
function refreshAwsCredentials() {
  clearTimeout(awsRenewalTimeout);

  // perform credentials renewal
  AwsService.refreshAwsCredentials()
    .then( function () {
      awsRenewalTimeout = setInterval(
        function () {
          refreshAwsCredentials();
        }, AWS.config.credentials.expireTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime() - 300000
      );
    })
    .catch( function (error) {
      // checks error, normally it basically logs in, then refreshes
    });
}
```

**AwsService.refreshAwsCredentials()**

```
if ( AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh() ) {
  AWS.config.credentials.refresh( function (error) {
    if (error) {
      // rejects promise with error message
    }
    else {
      // resolves promise
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: They should be valid for 1 hour. How are you checking that your credentials have timed out?

Comment: I periodically check AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh(), and if that indicates we need an update I perform the AWS.config.credentials.refresh().

If I then check the AWS.config.credentials.expireTime I can see the time has been extended

Comment: Can you update the question with some code? I found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499629/when-using-cognito-credentials-with-aws-in-a-browser-javascript-keep-getting) which is not exactly a duplicate but talks about the basic setup for what you are trying to do. See if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that I had a check for auth error where I was too specific. I checked for being logged in and not that the credentials had timed out. Now I attempt a login when things fail and the credential timeout is now resolved when needed.